# create add favorite button

Tags: mysql, database, button, profile

i have internet dating site and i would like to create for each profile an "add favorite" button, like this the client will be able to see the profiles he likes in his home page. The problem is that i don't know how to do.
i have two tables in my Data Base one for the "Clients" and one for "Profiles"

Someone can help me to start this work please?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add third table "favorite" with column as

User_Id

Favorite(link or item)

Answer (score 0):

You can used user_id in favorite table